# Tensorflow Models - Object Detection how to specify epochs details?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection, tensorflow-datasets

I am training the pascal dataset for object detection on my laptop, I get output as "Skipping training since max_steps has already saved", getting a step lower I could see that the pipeline file generated has the epochs as 1. I am looking how to specify the epochs to training model.

Command used - 
$ python object_detection/model_main.py --pipeline_config_path=/home/sshetty/github/lab/pascal/models/ssdlite_mobilenet_v2_coco/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.config --model_dir=/home/sshetty/github/lab/pascal/models/ssdlite_mobilenet_v2_coco/ --num_train_steps=50000 --alsologtostderr --verbosity=1 --stderrthreshold=debug

Output - 
I0124 17:29:36.659717 139972583880448 tf_logging.py:115] Start train and evaluate loop. The evaluate will happen after every checkpoint. Checkpoint frequency is determined based on RunConfig arguments: save_checkpoints_steps None or save_checkpoints_secs 600.
INFO:tensorflow:Skipping training since max_steps has already saved.
I0124 17:29:36.662388 139972583880448 tf_logging.py:115] Skipping training since max_steps has already saved.